# Interactive way to "git add" files from "git status" CLI?

Tags: git, command-line-interface

If I do `git status` from the CLI, I would like to just press up/down arrows to choose files with the spacebar to select files to "add" to my commit. For example:

```
[ ] modified: whatever.txt
[*] modified: whatever2.txt
```

whatever2.txt would be added that easily.

Seems to me something like this should exist already? To be more specific, I'd like the solution to use the bash CLI.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
git add -i
```

gives an interactive UI for staging. However it's not like what you are expecting, but a bit different. You can [check the documentation here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Interactive-Staging).

There's also this npm package [git-add-interactive](https://www.npmjs.com/package/git-add-interactive) that you can check out.